# groupby and count of values in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am having following values in excel/dataframe.

[image]

here I need to group by the values by 'Date' column and respectively need to put count of the other 2 field's values. like below,

[image]

I tried following code, but it's giving only count the dates.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

df1 = df['Date'].dt.date.value_counts().sort_index().reset_index()
df1.columns = ['DATE','Count']
```

note: having **million** of rows

Comment: please provide your input in a reproducible format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html)+[`groupby.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.value_counts.html):

```
g = df.melt(['ID', 'date']).groupby('date')

(df['date'].value_counts().to_frame(name='count')
 .join(g['value'].value_counts().unstack('value', fill_value=0))
 .rename_axis('date').reset_index()
)
```

Or [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the `groupby.value_counts`:

```
g = df.groupby('date')

pd.concat([g['date'].count().to_frame(name='count'),
           g['status'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0),
           g['from'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)],
         axis=1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
       date  count  False  True  road  water
0  01/02/23      4      2     2     3      1
1  01/04/23      2      1     1     2      0
2  01/22/23      1      1     0     1      0
3  01/03/23      1      0     1     0      1
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use pd.get_dummies:

```
pd.concat(
    [
        pd.get_dummies(
            df.set_index("date").drop("ID", axis=1), columns=["status", "from"]
        )
        .groupby(level=0)
        .sum(),
        df["date"].value_counts(),
    ],
    axis=1,
)
```

Output:

```
            status_FALSE  status_TRUE  from_road  from_water  date
2023-01-02             2            2          3           1     4
2023-01-03             0            1          0           1     1
2023-01-04             1            1          2           0     2
2023-01-22             1            0          1           0     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which is based on the idea of creating two pivot tables (one for `status` and another for `from`) and concatenating the two pivot tables:

```
out = df.drop('ID', axis=1)

aux = out.pivot_table(
    index='date', columns='status', values='status', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)

(pd.concat([
    aux.sum(axis=1).rename('count'),
    aux,
    out.pivot_table(
        index='date', columns='from', values='from', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)],
           axis=1)
 .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
        date  count  False  True  road  water
0   1/2/2023      4      2     2     3      1
1  1/22/2023      1      1     0     1      0
2   1/3/2023      1      0     1     0      1
3   1/4/2023      2      1     1     2      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way by using `pd.get_dummies()`:

```
(pd.get_dummies(df.iloc[:,1:],columns = ['status','from'],prefix = '',prefix_sep='')
.groupby('date').sum()
.join(df['date'].value_counts().rename('date_counts')))
```